# select count items each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables category and adverts, i need to select all categories and the number of adverts it has in the adverts table that has at least count greater than zero

the category table

```
cat_id   |  Name
----------------
1        | Toys
2        | fashion
3        | electronics
```

The adverts table

```
cat_id   |  title
 ----------------
1        | a
2        | b
2        | c
1        | d
2        | e
```

what i expect

```
cat_id  | count  | Name
-----------------------
1       |2       | a
2       |3       | b
```

The query i tried

```
Select 
c.name, c.cat_id,c.parent_id, @count:= (Select Count(av.cat_id) From adsview av Where av.cat_id = c.cat_id)
from 
category c  WHERE @count > 0
```

i am getting and empty result, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the `cat_id` from `category` table are in `adverts` table you need to join as

```
select 
c.cat_id,
c.Name,
count(a.cat_id) as `count` 
from category c 
join adverts a on a.cat_id = c.cat_id 
group by c.cat_id ;
```

Comment: please can you put the condition of count greater than 0

Comment: Inner join will meet that condition no need to add extra condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
select cat_id, count(*)
from adverts
group by cat_id;
```

So the mySQL query engine will grab every single row from the adverts table, it'll put them into neat piles where all rows in the pile have the same category, it'll count the number of rows in each pile, and then it'll return to you a result row for each pile with the pile's id and the number of rows.

Now lets add something: we want to also get the category's name. So we indicate that in the select clause, and add a join to the from clause. The join says "for every row in table a, consider it alongside every row in table b. if some condition holds, put this combined row into the from set". You can see that joins are actually quite slow in SQL (relatively).

```
select c.cat_id, count(*) as count, c.name
from adverts as a join categories as c on a.cat_id = c.cat_id
group by c.cat_id;
```

Note also that I've aliased the tables as a and c respectively, so as to remove the ambiguity over the column name cat_id (otherwise the mySQL query engine may get confused).

Comment: where is the category name in your result?

Comment: In original question (version 1) you asked "howto" without "name" column specified.

Comment: Yep, I feel like someone moved the goalpost ;) answer updated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, mate:

```
SELECT
    c.cat_id,
    COUNT(a.cat_id) AS count,
    a.title
FROM
    category c
    LEFT JOIN adverts a ON a.cat_id = c.cat_id
GROUP BY
    c.cat_id
HAVING
    count > 0;
```

or this:

```
SELECT
    c.cat_id,
    COUNT(a.cat_id) AS count,
    a.title
FROM
    category c
    INNER JOIN adverts a ON a.cat_id = c.cat_id
GROUP BY
    c.cat_id;
```

Comment: A count greater than 0 is an inner join

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, added an alternative answer.

Comment: Note that generally, non-aggregated columns in the select should also appear in the group by. MySQL forgives the omission but other RDBMSs do not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use group by function like below

```
select cat_id, count(*) as count
from adverts
group by cat_id;
```